# AWS RDS Load balacing

Tags: amazon-web-services

As far as I have understood the RDS on AWS can scale out by creating read replicas of the master database. And I need to take care in my application logic such that all the write requests go to the master database and read requests go to the slaves.

Q1. Is there any component that can sit between my EC2's (which are elastic) which can automatically route write requests to the masters and read requests to the slaves based on the query ?

Q2. Assuming there are 2 read replicas, do I still change my application logic to read from different replicas ?

Basically, is there any way I can have a load balancer in between my elastic beanstalk and RDS replicas such that I may not have to change much in my application logic. Reason is I am trying to port and not re-write.

Thanks
Sanket

Comment: If you're using Rails it might be worth checking out https://github.com/tchandy/octopus

Comment: You also might look into load balancing using Route53. Add a CNAME record with all your read replicas and do round-robin DNS load balancing. You'll still need to update app logic in order to route read to replicas and write to master, but this might take care of load balancing replicas.

Comment: Don't try and reinvent the wheel. RDS and read replicas handle this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q1. Is there any component that can sit between my EC2's (which are
>   elastic) which can automatically route write requests to the masters
>   and read requests to the slaves based on the query ?

You can use something like Amazon's Simple Queue Service to sit between your web and data tier or even something more complex like writing to Elasticache.

> Q2. Assuming there are 2 read replicas, do I still change my
>   application logic to read from different replicas

It's my understanding that read traffic (SELECTS) get routed to the read replicas while writes (insert/update/delete) get routed to the master and asynchronously update the read replicas. So I believe you just send your traffic to the RDS endpoint and it handles it from there.